# Can I use a MongoDB App Services trigger to prevent invalid data

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to have an insert/update trigger that cancels the update or insert if the underlying function detects invalid data in the document? Or is this not the intention of triggers and so not supported?

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: You don't need to use trigger for this. I suggest you to read the docs : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/core/schema-validation/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm already using schema validation...in this case it's more data related validation. example: I have a property in my document which can only contain data based upon another document.
So the way I see it is: schema validation is for datatype validation, while I need content validation.